# How should I talk to my airbnb host after I just arrived

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I booked a place on Airbnb and it is an entire house. I was wondering what I should say to the host when I first get there. Like first I need to let them know that I am the person who they are expecting so should I say something like "hey I am your Airbnb tenant?" or "I am your Airbnb guest".

Comment: You can say "Hallo, I am Joji." The host is expecting you, as you have booked. That makes it more definite than a random person who spots the host waiting and 'tries it on'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search confirmed that Airbnb refers to tenants as **guests**, so you could say:

> Hi, I am your Airbnb guest.

I would say something a bit more specific though, in case the person has numerous guests. I would probably say

> Hi, I booked your Airbnb from [beginning date] to [end date].